# Change font color from select option

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on some code, basically I have a form. On that form is a select option where I want users to select a font color.
I then need to append that option to an element on page, by adding the option they chose as a css class. Need to do this live.

So form element like so:

```
<select id="selectcolor" name="selectcolor" style="width: 200px;">
                        <option value="null">-- Select a Color ... --</option>
                        <option value="black">Black</option>
                        <option value="white">White</option>
                </select>
```

JS I made is:

```
//select text color
    $("#selectcolor").change(function(){
    var color = $(this).val();
    $(".selectcolor").css("color", 'color');
```

HTML to apply change to:

```
<div class="rightBottom selectcolor">Change this text<br />color</div>
```

Then in css I was gonna do:

```
.black {color:#000;}
.white {color:#fff;}
```

etc.

Basically, when user changes the select option, lets say to black, the class attribute changes text color to black on the div / span elements. Etc

Any suggestions please, I tried adding in select option values color:#000 etc but didnt work, I am guessing theres a couple of issues I am overlooking...

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#selectcolor').change(function() {
    var color = this.value || '';
    $('.selectcolor').attr('class', function(i, classes) {
        var cls = classes.split(/[\s]/);
        cls[2] = color;
        return cls.join(' ');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/347/)**

Comment: The only issue is, in the html it is doing : style="color: pink;" for pink, which isnt reflecting the .css class for pink in my case .pink: #ec008c; is there a way to get it to parse the #value instead of the color name value ?

Comment: Removed tick, because this adds style attribute but doesnt instantiate class, how we wanted.

Comment: If you could iterate that on jsfiddle, i cannot get it to work as reqd unfortunately.

Comment: Thankyou, will check immediately. And revise accepted answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you are using the constant 'color' instead of using variable color. 
Change the line :

```
 $(".selectcolor").css("color", 'color');
```

to:

```
$(".selectcolor").css("color", color)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

`$(".selectcolor").css("color", 'color');`

to

`$(".selectcolor").css("color", color);`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood right you want the element get the proper class name based on selected option value;

So, Here is the solution that comes to mind:

```
<select id="selectcolor" name="selectcolor" style="width: 200px;">
     <option value="null">-- Select a Color ... --</option>
     <option value="000000">Black</option>
     <option value="ffffff">White</option>
</select>

$("#selectcolor").change(function(){
    var color = $(this).val();
    $(".selectcolor").css('color', '#'+ color);
}
```

hope it helps you.  I did not test the code but the idea behind it is you make the option values as the color code without # sign so in the third line of query will paste the # to the string. Be careful when using a variable in the jQuery to not surround it by \' because it will interpret it as static text.